# Search a word which exactly match using python

Tags: python

I have Paragraph contains "I have a good python book so will become pythonist"
my aim is to search only "python" not pythonist how can I do it using python and not take any extra characters before and after

Comment: What is your desired result?  The position of this word in the string?  The number of occurrences of this word?

Comment: What about "I like Python's syntax."  Do you want to catch this or not?

Comment: I want only word not position because , after again I need to compare with another string

Comment: If you "want only the word", you don't have to do anything.  The word is "python".

Comment: Not sure I understand what you're asking.  If you just want to know if the word is in the text, you can use a [regular expression](http://www.python.org/doc//current/library/re.html), something like `if re.search('\spython\s', the_string_to_search):`.  Or do you want to know where the string is?

Comment: maybe it's useful for your case, search for Porter Stemmer

Comment: I tried with list Actually I converted to list then I checking with it like if "python" in list: print "value found" else : print "is different"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will find if there is an exact match with the word `'python'` by splitting all the words by whitespace.

```
>>> text = "I have a good python book so will become pythonist"
>>> 'python' in text.split()
True
```